# How to call from a shell program a postgresql COPY FROM FILE command, passing the path of the FILE as an argument?

Tags: postgresql, copy

I am trying to run, via a linux shell script, a Postgresql command that reads a CSV and updates a table with it.

The difficulty I am facing, is that this shell script has to pass an argument to the SQL program, argument that contains the path where the CSV is stored.

I just can't make it...

The PSQL command in my shell script is:

```
PSQL -f ${UNXSQLPATH}/new_nomenclature.sql - v v1=${UNXDATAPATH}
```

And the new_nomenclature.sql program contains the following line:

```
COPY nomenclature FROM :v1||'new_nomenclature.csv' CSV DELIMITER ';' HEADER ENCODING 'LATIN9';
```

Note: when I hardcopy the path in the SQL program, everything works fine.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Utility commands like `COPY` and many others do not accept expressions where **literals** are expected, so the file name must be given verbatim.

You may use `\set` in psql to build the filename by concatenating a path with a name, as in:

```
$ cat script.sql
\set path :v1 '/new_nomenclature.csv'
COPY nomenclature FROM :'path' CSV ....

$ psql -f script.sql -v v1="/tmp"
```

When `\set` is not suitable, another way is to call SELECT to build the string, get the result into a psql variable, and feed it back to COPY (this might come handy if building the path requires more than a mere concatenation)

```
$ cat script.sql
select :'v1' || '/new_nomenclature.csv' AS path \gset
COPY nomenclature FROM :'path' CSV ....
```

Comment: I am truly amazed by these two solutions : both work fine, and they are light and elegant ! But they require to be a PostgreSql "master", which I am not, and I will take some time to program like that. Thank you !